# Script URL Service Worker - Not allowed to follow a redirection while loading service-worker.js

Tags: javascript, service-worker

My current application is using Create React App. I've enabled the service worker and it's been working fine.

However, recently we've redirected our site from **https:site1.domain.com** to **https:site2.domain.com**, so when users land on **site1** they should automatically be redirected to **site2**.

But this doesn't happen to every user, there are some users that aren't redirected nor do they get any of the update code when there are new changes and can access **site1** as normal.

I implemented code to unregister all service workers on **site1** *only* but the likelyhood of the user getting this code is low to nil since I noticed the user doesn't get any new code updates.

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
    registration.unregister();
  });
}
    
caches
  .keys()
  .then(function (cacheNames) {
    cacheNames.forEach(function (cacheName) {
      caches.delete(cacheName);
    });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    alert("something went wrong");
   });
    
alert("reload app")
);
```

The codebase is all the same, but I did notice that I get a warning on the console on **site1**

```
Manifest: property 'start_url' ignored, should be same origin as document.
```

Is there a way I can get this fixed without the user having to hard reload?

Comment: If you still have control over site1.domain.com, you should be able to delete all data from that origin by using the [`Clear-Site-Data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Clear-Site-Data) header. There may be options that are less drastic, though.

Comment: @Jan is that done on the server side where we set up the subdomain redirect?

Comment: Yes, this is a response header. If you return the header `Clear-Site-Data: "storage"` for requests to site1.domain.com (together with the `Location` header for redirects), the browser should delete all kinds of storage including service worker registrations from this origin.

The [examples](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-clear-site-data/#examples) in the specification can help to understand the header a bit better.